# What will the integration be ?

Tags: special-functions

Using the orthogonality property of bessel function we have

[image]

Now what will be the formula for the following

[image]

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question? How are these integrals not identical?

Comment: @mtiano $a\neq b$ in the second integral.

Comment: in the second integral a and b are different unlike first

Comment: @mtino if u have any suggestion to solve the integral pls help me